# I would like simplify these code. Is there any idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#show00').click(function () {

    $('#n000,#n010,#n020,#n030,#n040,#n050,#n060,#n070').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide00').click(function () {
    $('#n000,#n010,#n020,#n030,#n040,#n050,#n060,#n070').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show01').click(function () {
    $('#n001,#n011,#n021,#n031,#n041,#n051,#n061,#n071').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide01').click(function () {
    $('#n001,#n011,#n021,#n031,#n041,#n051,#n061,#n071').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show02').click(function () {
    $('#n002,#n012,#n022,#n032,#n042,#n052,#n062,#n072').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide02').click(function () {

    $('#n002,#n012,#n022,#n032,#n042,#n052,#n062,#n072').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show03').click(function () {
    $('#n003,#n013,#n023,#n033,#n043,#n053,#n063,#n073').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide03').click(function () {

    $('#n003,#n013,#n023,#n033,#n043,#n053,#n063,#n073').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show04').click(function () {

    $('#n004,#n014,#n024,#n034,#n044,#n054,#n064,#n074').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide').click(function () {

    $('#n004,#n014,#n024,#n034,#n044,#n054,#n064,#n074').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show').click(function () {

    $('#n005,#n015,#n025,#n035,#n045,#n055,#n065,#n075').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide05').click(function () {

    $('#n005,#n015,#n025,#n035,#n045,#n055,#n065,#n075').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show06').click(function () {

    $('#n006,#n016,#n026,#n036,#n046,#n056,#n066,#n076').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide06').click(function () {

    $('#n006,#n016,#n026,#n036,#n046,#n056,#n066,#n076').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show07').click(function () {

    $('#n007,#n017,#n027,#n037,#n047,#n057,#n067,#n077').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide07').click(function () {

    $('#n007,#n017,#n027,#n037,#n047,#n057,#n067,#n077').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show08').click(function () {

    $('#n008,#n018,#n028,#n038,#n048,#n058,#n068,#n078').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide08').click(function () {

    $('#n008,#n018,#n028,#n038,#n048,#n058,#n068,#n078').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show09').click(function () {

    $('#n009,#n019,#n029,#n039,#n049,#n059,#n069,#n079').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide09').click(function () {

    $('#n009,#n019,#n029,#n039,#n049,#n059,#n069,#n079').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show010').click(function () {

    $('#n0010,#n0110,#n0210,#n0310,#n0410,#n0510,#n0610,#n0710').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide010').click(function () {

    $('#n0010,#n0110,#n0210,#n0310,#n0410,#n0510,#n0610,#n0710').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});

$('#show011').click(function () {

    $('#n0011,#n0111,#n0211,#n0311,#n0411,#n0511,#n0611,#n0711').stop(true, false).fadeIn();

});

$('#hide011').click(function () {

    $('#n0011,#n0111,#n0211,#n0311,#n0411,#n0511,#n0611,#n0711').stop(true, false).fadeOut();

});
```

Comment: I think it's too late to fix it, I'd start from scratch. Make use of common classes, instead of ids, and re-factor as you write the code.

Comment: learn to use loops :-)

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a loop would help your cause.

```
for(var i=0; i<=11; i++) {
  $('#show0' + i).click(function() {                     
    $('#n00' + i + ',#n01' + i + ',#n02' + i + ',#n03' + i + ',#n04' + i + ',#n05' + i + ',#n06' + i + ',#n07' + i).stop(true,false).fadeIn();
  });
  $('#hide0' + i).click(function() {                     
    $('#n00' + i + ',#n01' + i + ',#n02' + i + ',#n03' + i + ',#n04' + i + ',#n05' + i + ',#n06' + i + ',#n07' + i).stop(true,false).fadeOut();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help myself.  :/

```
$("[id^=show0],[id^=hide0]").click(function(e) {
    if (/^(hide|show)0(\d+)$/.test(this.id)) {
        var fade = RegExp.$1 == "show" ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut";
        var n = RegExp.$2;
        var selector = new Array(8).join(".").split(".").map(function(v, i) {
            return "#n0" + i + n;
        }).join(",");
        $(selector).stop(true, false)[fade]();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9H4xh/1/) (vs [your code for comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/9H4xh/))

---

That was kind of fun, but really this is a total hack.  [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421054/i-would-like-simplify-these-code-is-there-any-idea#comment32316331_21421054) is right.  Don't give elements incrementing ids.  Either give them each a meaningful id, or, if they are part of a set, give them a common class and access them by index if needed.

Beginner developers (and, sadly, some experienced developers) are tempted to copy and paste code when they need to do the same thing twice.  If you find yourself copying and pasting more than a couple lines of code, or even just a single line of code several times, stop. You can probably write a function to do it for you.  It pays dividends in the maintainability of your code.